# Hibernate parent Child mapping

Tags: hibernate

Working on mapping parent-child relation mapping in Hibernate and not able to find the best possible way to do this.Here is the description of the problem.

I have a class as parent and a child class which **do not have independent life cycle.** Here is mapping for my parent class

```
<class name="PARENT" table="PARENT">
    <id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="UUID" />
        <generator class="uuid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="creationDate" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="CREATIONDATE" />
    </property>
    <set name="childtable" table="CHILD" inverse="false" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="UUID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="CHILD" />
    </set>
```

here is Child class mapping

```
<class name="CHILDCLASS" table="CHILDCLASS">
    <id name="parentID" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PARENTCLASSID" />
        <generator class="uuid"/>
    </id>

    <property name="deperatureTime" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="DEPERATURETIME" />
    </property>
```

but I want is when the parent class gets persisted it will make child class persistant which is achievable but I want that in child class parentclassid field should have value of the identifier filed of parent class.

e.g

> if parent class ID value id 1 than the `PARENTCLASSID` filed of child
>   should have value 1

I am not sure if I am able to make sense of this question, if not please ask me and I will try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for something called one-to-one shared primary key mapping.
Does this help?
[Shared primary key in hibernate](http://www.hibernate-examples.com/2009/12/one-to-one-association-using-primary.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<class name="PARENTCLASS" table="parentTable">  
    <id name="parentID" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PARENTCLASSID" />
        <generator class="uuid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="deperatureTime" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="DEPERATURETIME" />
    </property>
    <set inverse="true" name="fieldName">
        <key>
            <column name="sql_id_name" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
    <one-to-many class="CHILDCLASS"/>
    </set>
</class>
```